# Quicksight count distinct IDs based on conditions from other column

Tags: if-statement, count, distinct, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I want to count unique IDs from one column based on values in other column. Count distinct ID if TYPE is both 'A' and 'M'.

| MONTH | ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 2 | M |
| 2 | 3 | A |
| 2 | 3 | M |
| 2 | 4 | M |
| 2 | 4 | M |
| 2 | 5 | A |
| 2 | 5 | A |

The example above should return 1 as ID = 3 has TYPE 'A' and 'M'.

Cheers, A.

Answer (score 0):

Make the calculated field:

```
distinctCountOver(TYPE,[ID],PRE_FILTER) -1
```

Then make a KPI visual with ID as the Value and aggregation set to "Count distinct" and add a Filter for your calculated field with "No aggregation" and Equal to 1.

[screenshot of Quicksight using the above instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flcKs.png)

This calculation works such that for more than two rows per ID, such as ID 6 having three rows with TYPES M, M and A, it will be counted as a positive in the results.

**Updated answer to Updated Question**

`distinctCountOver(TYPE,[ID,MONTH],PRE_AGG) - 1`

Plot this as a table, screenshot below, with MONTH as the Group and ID (Count Distinct) as the Value, apply a Filter for the above calculated field for No Aggregation, Greater than 0, Exclude Nulls.
This answer will give you the total distinct IDs, in each MONTH, with **more than** one TYPE.

**Note** I have added an additional ID = 6 with A,A in MONTH 2 and A,M in MONTH 3 to your data above and otherwise copied all your data above but with MONTH = 3, that is why you now get 2 total (distinct) IDs with different TYPE from the original formula and 1 and 2 in MONTH 2 and 3 in the table.

In this screenshot the original answer is in the first box, the followup answer is the table on the right. Cheers
[screenshot of Quicksight using the above instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXSgF.png)

Comment: Thanks for this @skabo. I would like to use the total in a calculated field formula. I added month column to the example as I would like to aggregate unique ids per month. In this case the sum would be 1.  I tried to use: 
`distinct_countIf(ID, (distinctCountOver(TYPE,[ID,MONTH],PRE_FILTER) -1) > 0)` but am getting this error "CONTEXTUAL_NESTED_AGGREGATION". Would you know how to approach this issue? Cheers, A.

Comment: Yeah, AWS is made to visualise and make relatively complex calculations but it will NEVER do nested aggregations. This leaves you with 3 options: re-organise your calculations into a linear series of aggregations (you still can't nest using different calculated fields); use aggregations to label and then filter your calculations (what i did here); use a proper data ETL tool to do your calculations before loading into Quicksight - I do this regularly, loading the raw data and a couple of precalculated aggregate data tables made from the raw data. Include label columns in all of them to filter.