# Amazon QuickSight - Working out size of network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a database table with a record for each IOT device connected, each device has a unique device id and a unique network id associated with it.

For example:

| device_id | network_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |

I would like to be able visualise the size of each network based on its id. So I would have an output like such based on the above data:

| network_id | size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |

I'm not currently sure how to do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67658326/quicksight-count-distinct-ids-based-on-conditions-from-other-column

Comment: The answer for this only gives a count for those with certain conditions, in that case it only adds to the count when there are two values in a different column. I'm sure the distinctCountOver function is the right directions though

Comment: It appears there is not distinctCountOver function, just countOver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the countOver function worked for this

I made a calculated field called NetworkSize which was defined as:

```
countOver
(
  {device_id}
  ,[{network_id}]
)
```

Which gives the right output I was looking for

[image: Using countOver function output]

However I have to include device_id in the visual which is a bit inconvenient